# Caching HTML / Performance: How can I speed up page loads when 50+% of the transferred bytes are for nav menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, caching

I have a very large, very complicated website.  Like many, it has a lot of common HTML across pages, namely the navigation and top ribbon.

A single (very complicated) page can take up to 300KB (of almost exclusively HTML) to load.  Of that almost *half* is the HTML which is common in the nav and top ribbon.  These elements **only ever change** when a new version of the site is updated.

The `content` pane of *every* page is unique, but again, the nav and top ribbon (which account for ~50% of the page's data) do not change.

**How can I speed up my general page load speeds?**  I've got two ideas below, but given the site is already *huge* and very well established, the pros and cons of each possible solution are very important.

1. Make jQuery (JavaScript) store the nav menu in a `common_html.js` file which populated targeted divs with the 100s of KBs of common data.  Therefore the browser will (hopefully) cache the `common_html.js` file and, by not re-downloading it ever page, allow the common code to be injected almost instantly.
2. Use AJAX loading of the main `content` div, pushing the URL states as changes are made.  This seems to be the common Facebook approach, but applying it to a large, existing website (where I am currently the sole dev) makes me wonder the difficulty (and performance) of this approach compared to others.

Which of these are better, or **is there a better/faster option I'm missing?**  Time to implement is just about as important as performance gains are!

Comment: be aware of the SEO implications and adjustments needed for both approaches

Comment: Not a concern in my case.  The website requires login; there is a completely different site for marketing the services.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the main issue could be DOM (Document Object Model) rendering.  If it truly is just a ton of HTML, you want to minimize the things which force you to re-render the dom.

If it's the menu which is really just super large; it might be worth going with option 2 (although in this case I may suggest using something like AngularJS or even facebook's React).

Speaking of Facebook's REACT library; they have a concept called a "Virtual DOM" that makes rendering DOM elements significantly faster.

Make your decision on what you implement based on which has less html to change, so you are only rendering HTML intensive things once.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly speed to implement is going to be opposite run-time speed here.

These are both reasonable options.  Of course there are pros and cons to each.

Option 1 will almost certainly be quicker and easier to implement.  Assuming that you already have some common server-side code for those portions shared among the many pages, then you can simply convert that to something that will create an equivalent client-side.  Once you get it to work, it should work equally well on all pages.  (There might be a few gotchas about pathing, but they won't be hard.)  The downside is that this won't work as well with SEO.  And it will likely take a noticeably longer time to load the page than would option 2.

Option 2 is more work, as you have to find a way to intercept all calls to the server, and translate them into the correct AJAX calls.  It feels like the more modern solution, and would probably have a perceptibly faster user reponse time.  But it would take significantly more time to implement.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest factors that a lot of people forget is gzipping your content.

Are you doing it?

If you are telling me that your html is 300kb i'm assuming not (I hope not at least).  Gzipping can compress that up to ~90% meaning that 300kb can be ~30kb total.

Here is Google's take on gzip: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/optimize-encoding-and-transfer#text-compression-with-gzip

In the example they give when they gzip bootstrap-3.1.1.css (118kb) they can compress it down to 18kb (85% savings).

Here is another resource to check if your site is using gzip or not: http://checkgzipcompression.com/

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but not relevant to this specific question.  This question is about caching my OWN generated HTML, not about caching external resources.

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with caching anything.  Your question was "How can I speed up page loads".   Deferring 300kb of html to javascript is not going to make anything faster.  Compressing 300kb to 30kb on the other hand is going to make a huge difference.

Comment: "Deferring" the data from HTML (which doesn't cache) to an external, stand-alone JavaScript file (which should) wouldn't do anything?  Are you sure?  *That* **would** answer my question.